# Reset class when pressed using Jquery css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, audio

I am working on an audio player that prevents users from right click saving target as... while also obscuring file path using Jquery. It also only allows one sound to play at once.

So far everything works perfect except when the sound that is currently playing is clicked, the class doesn't reset to play (Green Color)

have so far with Jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pt3cx1eo/12/

**Jquery:**

```
     $(".play").on('click',function(){
         var key = $(this).attr('key');     
         EvalSound(key);
         $(".play").removeClass("pause"); // somewhere here is where it needs to be changed / fixed I believe 
         $( this ).toggleClass( "pause" );
     });

    var thissound = new Audio();
    var currentKey;
        function EvalSound(key) {



       if(currentKey !== key)
         thissound.src = "http://designlab360.org/fhi/splash/dev2/audio/" + key + ".mp3";      
         currentKey = key;

         if (thissound.paused)
                    thissound.play();
            else
                thissound.pause();
                thissound.currentTime = 0;
                 currentPlayer = thissound;




        }
```

**CSS:**

```
.play
{
color:green;    
}

.pause

{
color:red;  
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p><span class="play" key="wash-song1_2">Play</span></p>    
<p><span class="play" key="wash-song2_2">Play</span></p>    
<p><span class="play" key="wash-song3_2">Play</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are always removing the pause class from every element that has the play class before you toggle the pause class for the relevant clicked element.

I have changed it so that you only remove all OTHER elements that isn't the clicked element.

Example:

```
$(".play").on('click',function(){
     var key = $(this).attr('key');     
     EvalSound(key);
     var this_play = $(this);
     $(".play").each(function() {
         if ($(this)[0] != this_play[0]) {
             $(this).removeClass("pause");
         }
     });
     $( this ).toggleClass( "pause" );
 });
```

It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/wyfjdgyb/1/